# How can I analyze xdebug function-tracing output

Tags: php, xdebug, code-analysis

I am creating function-tracing `xt` files with `xdebug` which are are created with `php` commands [like](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-02/21-understanding_php_code_better_with_xdebug)

```
xdebug_start_trace('outfile')
... code ...
xdebug_stop_trace();
```

How can I analyze/visualize the created data?

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Answer (score 1):

[**See the documentation**](https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) and the answers to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456395/xdebug-trace-gui).

You may be able to use https://github.com/corretge/xdebug-trace-gui. There are also other tools available, such as [ValaXdebugTools](https://github.com/technosophos/ValaXdebugTools) and [XDebugUtils](https://github.com/technosophos/XdebugUtils).

And, of course, you can always roll your own solution.

Comment: The link to chepri,com is broken

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota I've updated the answer to link directly to the tools in question; thanks.

Comment: Note: xdebug-trace-gui is not compatible with xdebug3